# Is there a way to set UWP Textbox to overwrite?

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to implement a text box in UWP with overwrite - when user types over existing text I want the old character to be delete and not inserted.

I've tried the same solution that worked with WPF, but there is no TextEditor or anything similar in UWP

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PlaceholderText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.placeholdertext#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBox_PlaceholderText) property for the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GettingFocus event and the PlaceholerText property.

```
private void TextBox_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    var textbox = (sender as TextBox);
    textbox.PlaceholderText = textbox.Text;
    textbox.Text = "";
}
```

Use the LosingFocus event to detect if the text changed and if the text didnt change, restore the old text.

```
private void TextBox_LosingFocus(UIElement sender, LosingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    var textbox = (sender as TextBox);
    // if the user didnt change the text, restore the old text input
    if (textbox.Text == "")
    {
        textbox.Text = textbox.PlaceholderText;
        textbox.PlaceholderText = "";
    }
}
```